# Pushing data that is not merged to a new DF, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DFs see below:

DF1

```
ID           Green             
B1           20        
B2           10        
B3            5      
B4            2      
B5            0       
B8            0
```

DF2

```
ID           Red               
B1           2        
B2           4        
B3           10        
B9           12        
B7           10
```

I've done a merge of the two dataframes with the following:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how = 'left', left_on='ID, right_on='ID')

ID         Green       Red               
B1           20        2       
B2           10        4       
B3            5       10
```

Is there a way for the data in DF1 that did not get matched/merged to be pushed to a new dataframe (e.g DF4) and the same for the data in DF2 to also get pushed to a new dataframe (e.g DF5)?

So DF4 and DF5 would be:

DF4

```
ID           Green                  
    B4            2      
    B5            0       
    B8            0
```

DF5

```
ID           Red                       
B9           12        
B7           10
```

Thank you for any insight or guidance.

Kind regards,

Comment: I imagine you can use `how='outer'` and manage differences with the NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to manage this is to pull in all the data into a single dataframe - simply change the how to 'outer'.

> DF3 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how = 'left', left_on='ID, right_on='ID')

And then you can access the union of the two by calling:

> DF3.dropna(thresh=1)

And you can access the ones with only red values calling:

> DF3.loc[DF3['Green'].isna()]

If you call the inverse, DF3['Red'].notna() you end up with both rows with a Green value and a Red value as well as the rows with a Red value and a NaN for the green.  So you have to call all the rows.  See below if you truly want just one column for the red or green.

> DF3.loc[DF3['Green'].isna()].drop(labels = 'Green')

Answer (score 1):

You can see the differences in both dataframes, parts that will not be merged, by checking which parts are in one and not the other. For example,

```
DF1[~DF1.isin(DF2)].dropna()
```

Result:

```
    ID  Green
3   B4  2
4   B5  0
5   B8  0
```

and

```
DF2[~DF2.isin(DF1)].dropna()
```

result:

```
    ID  Red
3   B9  12
4   B7  10
```